# Xamarin Android: Could not load assembly 'Bolts.AppLinks

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have already filed a bug report on Xamarin's bugzilla since error says I should.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42535

Here is the problem:

It was all fine until my Xamarin.Forms project started to give this error when I try to build it Android.

Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Bolts.AppLinks, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?    PMApp.Droid

I don't even remember updating anything.

Here is what I have tried so far: (Note: I have always deleted both bin and obj folders from Forms and Android project after doing these)

- Restarted VS
- Restarted PC
- Removed Xamarin.Facebook.Android via Nuget
- Removed Xamarin.Bolts via Nuget
- Removed the folders of Facebook and Android from the packages folder and let Nuget restore them
- Downgraded Bolts to 1.3.0, which downgraded Xamarin.Facebook.Android to 4.10.0

Comment: Hey! Would it be possible to add a sample of the app on your bug report? You can make the attachment private, or the entire bug private, if you need to protect the app. This way, only Xamarin team members will have access to it. It can help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: Sorry, but you are not allowed to (un)mark comments or attachments as private it gives me this error.

Comment: Hey, I marked the bug as private. You should still have access, but nobody else outside the Xamarin team. Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know if you are unable to access it

Comment: It is been so long, any progress?